# Rails Tutorial: No Relationship Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I am following the rails controller and am confused as to why their isn't a controller. I don't recall it asking me to generate one but should I? I'm confused? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, relationship controller is created in "12.2.4 A working follow button the standard way", if we're talking about Rails 3 version of this book.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to have a controller in order to complete the MVC (Model-View-Controller). The controller is an essential part of how Rails generates pages for your users.

You can find information about controllers here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Here's a simple tutorial on controllers:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-controller-methods.htm

Without more detail about your tutorial it's hard to be more specific. That said, I hope the above information is helpful to you in figuring how how to move forwards.